# Installation of an assembly to GAC both for mono/.NET

Tags: .net, mono, gac

As far as I know, for installation of an assmebly for .NET is as follows.

```
 'gacutil /i nunit.framework.dll'
```

And for the mono, set the directory to MONO_PATH is doing the job.

- Is this correct?
- With .NET/windows, where does the assembly installed? I couldn't see any change in c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\GAC_MSIL, after running the gacutil command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to install a .NET assembly to the GAC. You use `gacutil`, in windows or with mono:

```
$ gacutil -i gac_lib.dll
```

See the [mono documentation](http://www.mono-project.com/Assemblies_and_the_GAC#Installing_Assemblies_to_The_GAC).

Comment: What's the difference between install into GAC and attach the path to MONO_PATH with mono?

Comment: @prosseek - If all you want is to have the assembly globally accessible, then there is no difference. See what the documentation has to say about what should be installed in the GAC - http://www.mono-project.com/Assemblies_and_the_GAC#What_Should_Be_Installed_to_the_GAC