# How do you provide ResizeArray to legacy F# apps?

Tags: f#, mono

I'm building TrueSkill, the F# app, from 2008, on Mono 3.0 with F# 3.0.  The two errors I get are

`fList |> ResizeArray.iter (fun f -> f.ResetMarginals())` and

`let sumLogS = fList |> ResizeArray.fold_left (fun acc f -> acc + (f.LogNormalisation ())) 0.0`.

For F# 1.9, `ResizeArray` came from the PowerPack.  Apparently there's a PowerPack on github now.  But the standard Mono docs show that `ResizeArray<T>` is just an alias for `List<T>`.  Do I need to get the original `ResizeArray`, and if so, how would I do just that from the PowerPack, using the `ResizeArray.fs`?  What's the current relationship between `List` and `ResizeArray`?

Comment: `List<'t>==ResizeArray<'t>` but you don't get the methods (`.iter,.fold_left1`) for free, so you need to include the Powerpack.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To clarify, [ResizeArray<'T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee353447.aspx) is also an alias for `List<'T>` in .NET. Only high-order functions from `ResizeArray` module are provided by F# PowerPack.

Because there is no dependency on [this module](https://github.com/fsharp/powerpack/blob/master/src/FSharp.PowerPack/ResizeArray.fs), it is recommended to copy *ResizeArray.fs* directly to your project. You probably have to change a few function names to match the new `ResizeArray` module e.g. changing `fold_left` to `fold` and `fold_right` to `foldBack`.

Comment: I did copy, added ResizeArray.fs to project in MonoDevelop, and rename fold_left to fold; yet ResizeArray.iter and fold are still not found although.  The namespace Microsoft.FSharp.Collections is shared.  If I rename it to something else it's not found in the including file.  How do I make sure the caller file sees the newly copied ResizeArray.fs?

Comment: Make sure that you remove reference to F# Powerpack (to avoid confusion) and `ResizeArray.fs` appears before any module calling it in the project order.

Comment: Cool, works.  Now how do I install this ResizeArray.fs into GAC and refer to it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. The idea of copying *ResizeArray.fs* to your project is to avoid dificulties in compiling and installing assembiles. You can compile `ResizeArray` to a dll and install it to GAC using the technique described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000455/installation-of-an-assembly-to-gac-both-for-mono-net).

Comment: Yes, I'd rather install ResizeArray.fs as a DLL per link, to avoid copying it around, thx.